How do humans 4-colour?
I've recently been playing a lot of Killer Sudoku. One of the great features of the app I use is that it can 4-colour the cages to make the whole grid more human-readable, like so:

The existence of such a colouring is guaranteed by the 4-colour theorem, but this got me to thinking about how I (meaning me, specifically, not a computer) would find such a colouring. As someone who doesn't know a lot of graph theory, I always assumed the proof of the 4-colour theorem was non-constructive: naïvely, I had in my head that if there were an algorithm that provably converged to a solution then the proof wouldn't have required so many computer-assisted checks.
From searching around, I have found Robertson, Sanders, Seymour, and Thomas - Efficiently four-coloring planar graphs which gives an $O(n^2)$ algorithm — see Algorithm 1 and Theorem 2. This is already much better than I expected, but would still take me a very long time to do by hand (in my example below, there are ~30 cages, which are the regions in the graph to be coloured).
So my question is: are there any other algorithms that a human could feasibly apply to a reasonably small problem like this puzzle? I would be happy for a solution that exploits some extra structure here, but doesn't work for the whole class of loopless planar graphs. Even any results that don't apply to this exact example, but would solve a similar case would be very interesting to me.

Can't you get any planar graph using these grids by saying that vertices are giant squares and connecting them with narrow chains?

Are you sure it four-colours them?  The grid you've supplied has five colours (middle row, right-hand side, there's a single light-blue rectangle plus the green, pink, purple and yellow otherwise used).

@postmortes hah, you're right, although I think my question still stands. I'll generate a few and see if I can find a genuine example.

I think that these grids are easy to 4-colour since they typically have quite a few faces of degree 3 or less. All you need is to 4-colour the subgraph induced by faced of degree at most 4, and in that subgraph there are again few vertices of degree 3 or less....
